# GIT multiple command in one line error

Tags: git, macos, shell

When I run `git add . & git commit -m "some fix" & git push` it returns an error:

```
<user> alexis$ git add . & git commit -m "Add some fix" & git push
[1] 32595
[2] 32596
fatal: Unable to
create'/Users/<user>/Desktop/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
Everything up-to-date
[1]-  Done                    git add .
[2]+  Exit 128                git commit -m "Add some fix"
```

When I execute all cmd one by one, there is no problem.

Comment: Use double `&&` instead of single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single ampersand(`&`) after command in shell means to run the command in background. From your logs you can se jobs/process went background, which enables the command run in parallel

```
<user> alexis$ git add . & git commit -m "Add some fix" & git push
[1] 32595
[2] 32596
```

Where `&&` in shell means "logical AND", and `||` means "logical OR". you can find these used wisely in lot of startup/init scripts like ( jboss, tomcat )

```
[ -f "$file" ] && cat $file # cat the file only the file exists and regular file
```